# show hide content on mouseover boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Please can someone assist, looks like such a simple function but for the life of me I cannot get it right. I need to have it inserted on my wordpress website.

Its a simple show hide content when mouseover on another block. Exactly like the one on [**this site**](http://www.assistancesoftware.com/), under the heading Solutions. I mouseover the title block and I see the content on the right hand side.

Is there a very simple way to this? Or even a WP plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you simply create the HTML, CSS for the boxes, than one DIV for more DIV containing the desired content > than on mouseenter you show the respective text using jQuery or plain JS if you like.

Comment: You want to create that dropdown menu?

Comment: Alister... see this http://jsbin.com/xehefu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks Roko! Looks like you have nailed it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this for you, but if you have no knowlegde of coding it might be hard to add alone.

https://jsfiddle.net/Skaadel/5s7symfe/

Jquery

```
$('#puppies').hover(function() {
  $('.display').html('Puppies'); /** Change ('Puppies') to change text displayed when hover**/
});

$('#kittens').hover(function() {
  $('.display').html('Kittens');/** Change ('Kittens') to change text displayed when hover**/
});

$('#aardvark').hover(function() {
  $('.display').html('Aardvark'); 
/** Change ('Aardvark') to change text displayed when hover**/
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div id ="kittens"></div>
  <div id ="aardvark"></div>
  <div id ="puppies"></div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="display">Hover on the picture for description.</div>
```

CSS

```
    body { background: black; }

.display {
  font:20pt 'Georgia';
  height:50px;
  width: 759px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
.container{
height: 250px;
width: 759px;
margin: auto;
border: 3px solid black;
}

#kittens{
  background-image: url(http://goo.gl/Ktu3u0);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#aardvark{
  background-image: url(http://goo.gl/qQUUff);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#puppies{
  background-image: url(http://goo.gl/6gvDn2);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I made it fast, so the design is not that pretty.

Comment: Use classes instead of creating 8 (or more) separate functions

Comment: Ah! I'm still new to using Jquery and JS. Would you mind showing me best way to set it up? I would appreciate it if you had the time to change the Jsfiddle so i could see it.

Comment: See the demo I posted in the comments sections to the Original Poster

Answer (score 1):

I just created a simple solution. Check this below or https://jsfiddle.net/oneness/Lotaaxdh/

JS/CSS/HTML RESPECTIVELY

```js
                   
$( ".science" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( "#social_display" ).hide("fast"); 
  $( "#science_display" ).show("slow");
});

$( ".social" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( "#science_display" ).hide("fast");
  $( "#social_display" ).show("slow");
});
```

```css
.box{
    background-color: #37545c;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
#science_display, #social_display {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='left'>
<div class="box science">Science</div><br>
<div class="box social">Social</div>
</div>

<div class='right'>
<div id='science_display'>This is the story behind Science</div>
<div id='social_display'>Social button story and other details </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the way to go with jQuery, programming should be fun, not a copy-paste end editing nightmare. Be DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Create one function and stick to it.

Comment: Also, in your example, a faster mousemove over multiple elements will create animation buildups.